# After Success Execution i got error :Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am reading an sql article on how to cleverly use sql queries ,i get the bellow article which is calculating factorial and its working for number 5 but when i change to another number bigger than 12 it  push the error:Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
I think about 12 is the sum of numbers<=5 which are 5 4 3 2
the bellow query is working for all num<12 but when i change num to bigger than 12
it does not work even if i change the condition "num<"

```
 with fact as (
        select 1 as fac, 1 as num
        union all
        select fac*(num+1), num+1
        from fact
        where num<12)
    select fac
    from fact
    where num=5
```

Comment: Is there something you don't understand about the error message?  Ints only hold values up to 2 billion or so.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes you are right , do you mean i have to cast the result as nvarchar or as bigint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is a little strange -- counting up and then using the outer `where` to stop.

I would just put in one number and count down.  If you use `decimal(38, 0)`, you can go much higher:

```
with fact as (
        select cast(1 as decimal(38, 0)) as fac, 33 as num
        union all
        select fac * num, num - 1
        from fact
        where num > 0
       )
select max(fac)
from fact;
```

This returns 8,683,317,618,811,886,495,518,194,401,280,000,000.  That seems sufficiently large for most practical application.

Comment: thats right thanks @Gordon Linoff,would you please mention books or sources that has such rich and tricky query examples?

Comment: I have written a book (two if you count each edition) on SQL.  Other than that, Stack Overflow is not a place to recommend off-site resources.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the calculation when using the number 13 is greater than the r[ange of values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) an integer can hold

Instead you will have to convert to `BIGINT`

```
with fact as (
                select   CONVERT(BIGINT,1) as fac,
                         1  as num
                union all
                select   CONVERT(BIGINT,fac*(num+1)),
                         num+1
                from     fact
                where    num<13
             )
select fac
from fact
where num=13
```